# Question about Kernel

Tags: kernel

I am a linux noob recently I have tried latest ubuntu distros but it seems that my pc does not support latest kernel versions. So, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then updated that Ubuntu to 18.04. The problem is that my PC is running fine on kernel(4.4.0-210-generic) but does not run on kernel that comes with ubuntu 18. I wanted to ask is it okay if I am using Ubuntu 18.04 through kernel 4.4.0-210-generic
Thanks

Comment: You're aware that Ubuntu releases using the *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 18) are different products to those using the *year.month* format (ie. 18.04).  18 is not the same as 18.04.  Ubuntu LTS releases come with kernel stack choices; GA, HWE & OEM (*depending on your hardware*) but you should be specific with details  (kernel 4.4 was the GA kernel stack from 16.04 not 14.04; it was an HWE *option* on 14.04 as 14.04 came with the 3.13 kernel at release)

Comment: I am now using ubuntu 18.04 through kernel 4.4.0-210

Comment: Correct your question then, as 18.04 & 18 are different; and I hope your system is off-line given your kernel doesn't receive security patches (they are available only using ESM for the *xenial* kernels).  If your system is off-line you needn't worry; but security is your concern as 4.4 (a *xenial* or 16.04 kernel) isn't patched on a *bionic* (18.04) system meaning all security back-porting is your responsibility. My option would be the *oldest* or GA kernel option for 18.04; where you likely were using HWE (*but weren't specific, but as 14.04 used the 3.13 kernel you weren't using GA*)

Comment: If you're confused over my mention of kernels; the following maybe helpful - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack  and  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   ; in summary GA = the initial kernel a system gets (the most *stable* option), 3.13 for 14.04, 4.4 for 16.04, 4.15 for 18.04 etc... HWE = *hardware enablement* options that change over first couple of years of life, which allow later kernels to be used; OEM is *optional* kernels that suit particular hardware better etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't run" on a new kernel.

Comment: what I mean is that when I try to run a latest kernel it shows kernel panic error no matter which distro i choose

Comment: Staying with the kernel from a previous release of Ubuntu suggests that your method for upgrading from 14.04 to 18.04 was faulty or unsupported, or that you encountered a problem during that upgrade process that you have not disclosed in your Question.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely okay, it's not illegal to use unsupported software, but Ubuntu developers don't promise it will work. Using outdated kernel is very unlikely to cause problems in applications. However it would be better if you post your hardware (may be in another question), describe what you do and what you get (with logs, screenshots, photos, etc), find out which piece of software is written wrong and report a bug to it's developer.