# Questinon about kernel version

Tags: kernel

I am using  Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 4.4.0-210-generic. I can not use any new kernel because my system does not support kernel after 4.4.0-210-generic.I wanted to ask should I update my Ubuntu to the latest version while using old kernel. I want to try new features that comes with new kernel is there any way that I can use new features while still using old kernel,thanks
I am new to Linux

Comment: Can you elaborate " my system does not support kernel after 4.4.0-210-generic"? What a mysterious system you have?

Comment: maybe you should focus on fixing the "I can not use any new kernel because my system does not support kernel after 4.4.0-210-generic." Because I am with @Pilot6  I would assume there is no  reason for that. If you have a very old system you might need to use Budgie or Lubuntu but the kernel number should not be the problem,

Comment: Is it a 32-bit system?

Comment: from grub whenever I choose any other kernel i always get a kernel panic error also I have tried to install various other distro but always an kernel panic error I installed ubuntu 14 first then I updated to 16 and then 18.04 through ubuntu build in updater. Recently I updated to ubuntu 18.04 but when i select the kernel that comes with it it always show an kernal panic error

Comment: So what is "your system"? Did you try to boot from e.g Ubuntu 20.04 LiveUSB?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question about Kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415851/question-about-kernel)